# Inserting hyperlinks in pyplot interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I am creating a visualization of Twitter user locations as tweets come in, and so within my matplotlib code I have these three lines to create an interactive plot so the location markers can be plotted in realtime:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
plt.show()
```

What I'd like to do is add links to the original Tweet page within each marker.  So if you hover over a newly-added marker, you can click it and it opens up a browser and shows you the tweet.

I'm hoping there's a way to add hyperlinks that are clickable in real-time, but I'm okay with saving the visualization to an .svg and then seeing the links appear in a static file within my browser.  I see [this example page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hyperlinks.html) on how to do it, but it includes a plt.figure() statement which I don't have in my code.  How can I still produce the .svg with hyperlinks while running in interactive mode?

Comment: That is an application I never would have thought of....I suspect that it should be do this with call backs on picker events

Comment: There is also a gtkcairo gui-backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution you could try is by using the *matplotlib.use('SVG')* before you use savefig.

Straight from the FAQ (http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html) You have:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3])
plt.savefig('myfig')
```

Replace Agg with SVG and hopefully that will work for you.